# Java Sound API: Reading and writing to and from sound Ports

Tags: java, javasound, pulseaudio

I have a mixer that is returning a Port instead of a SourceDataLine. How do I read data from that port? I can't find any subclasses of Port. I'm probably missing something very obvious, but I just can't find any read or write classes that I can access the port from.

Edit: I'm trying to use the java pulseaudio extension from icedtea to play sound to mixers other than the default one.

Edit #2: Elsewhere in the java sound api, I appears that if you request for a Port.Info, it will actually return a target/source dataline. I haven't tested this theory out yet, but I looked at other people's source code. The problem is, the mixer I'm using is returning a Subclass of Port, not a Target/source dataLine.

Comment: Looks like [Ports](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Port.html) *are simple lines for input or output of audio to or from audio devices*. Port extends [Line](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Line.html). See if those help.

Comment: Line does not have any read and write functions, and port does not extends SourceDataLine or TargetDataLine. I also can't find a subclass of port that has read and write support.